# functional equations problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that satisfy $$ f(x)  + 3 f\left( \frac {x-1}{x} \right) = 7x $$
for all nonzero $x$.

Not sure how to go about this. I tried substituting some values in, but I'm getting nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The trick is that if $g(x)=\frac{x-1}{x}$, then $g(g(x))=-x+1$.

Thus $g(g(g(g(x))))=x$. You can use the following equations: $$f(x)+3f(g(x))=7x$$ $$f(g(x))+3f(g(g(x)))=7g(x)$$$$f(g(g(x))+3f(g(g(g(x))))=7g(g(x))$$$$f(g(g(g(x))))+3f(x)=7g(g(g(x)))$$